# https connection using CURL from command line

Tags: curl, ssl, command-line, https, certificate

I am new to Curl and Cacerts world and facing a problem while connecting to a server.
Basically, I need to test connectivity over https from one machine to another machine.
I have a URL to which I need to connect from Machine A (a linux machine)
I tried this on command prompt

```
cmd> curl https://[my domain or IP address]
```

and got the following:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

On going through some articles over internet I did this:

```
openssl s_client -connect <domain name or Ip address>:443
```

and got some response including the
server certificate (inside `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE-----`).

What should I do next from here. I think, I will have to just copy paste the text inside
`BEGIN CERTIFICATE & END CERTIFICATE` and save it in a file.
But, 
What type of file it should be? `.pem`, `.crt` ?..
What should I be do after that?

I tried this - copied the text inside `BEGIN CERTIFICATE & END CERTIFICATE` and saved it in a `.crt` file  - named it as `my-ca.crt` (also tried the same thing by naming it as `my-ca.pem` file)
and then did this:

```
cmd>curl --cacert my-ca.crt https://[my domain or IP address]
```

But got the same error.

Comment: Not sure about the solution you're suggesting, but I was just looking for similar info and I found this useful site for using curl with PHP http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: you can also add `--insecure` to disregard the SSL error.

Comment: newer versions of curl (e.g. 7.64) would not recognize older ciphers like RC4-SHA - using older version of curl (7.46) helped me https://serverfault.com/questions/889631/curl-fails-to-retrieve-https-content-error14094410ssl-routinesssl3-read-byte

Answer (score 215):

I had the same problem - I was fetching a page from my own site, which was served over HTTPS, but curl was giving the same "SSL certificate problem" message. I worked around it by adding a `-k` flag to the call to allow insecure connections.

```
curl -k https://whatever.com/script.php
```

Edit: I discovered the root of the problem. I was using an SSL certificate (from StartSSL, but I don't think that matters much) and hadn't set up the intermediate certificate properly. If you're having the same problem as user1270392 above, it's probably a good idea to [test your SSL cert](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) and fix any issues with it before resorting to the `curl -k` fix.

Comment: -k flag is a nice shortcut. Worked for me!

Answer (score 78):

### Basic certificate info

That's my everyday script:

```
curl --insecure -vvI https://www.example.com 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { cert=0 } /^\* SSL connection/ { cert=1 } /^\*/ { if (cert) print }'
```

**Output:**

```
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Los Angeles; O=Verizon Digital Media Services, Inc.; CN=www.example.org
*  start date: Dec 10 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Dec  9 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x5588e1f5ae30)
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
* Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact
```

### Full certificate info

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -text
```

Comment: Thus, you are allowing an `--insecure` connection through TSL, everyday...

Comment: @Brethlosze Thanks for your comment. But, that's not the case. The point is to get the SSL information from all sorts of certificates.

Comment: I dont see how this is a solution? This might return some ssl info, but you haven't explained how this is relevant to the question. And @Brethlosze is correct, if you are using this (even for gathering info) you are _not_ using SSL to fetch that info, and this means your requests are wide open to abuse.

Answer (score 49):

You need to provide the entire certificate chain to curl, since curl no longer ships with any CA certs. Since the cacert option can only use one file, you need to concat the full chain info into 1 file

Copy the certificate chain (from your browser, for example) into DER encoded binary x.509(.cer). Do this for each cert.

Convert the certs into PEM, and concat them into 1 file.

```
openssl x509 -inform DES -in file1.cer -out file1.pem -text
openssl x509 -inform DES -in file2.cer -out file2.pem -text
openssl x509 -inform DES -in file3.cer -out file3.pem -text

cat *.pem > certRepo

curl --cacert certRepo -u user:passwd -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "https//somesecureserver.com/rest/field"
```

I wrote a blog on how to do this here: http://javamemento.blogspot.no/2015/10/using-curl-with-ssl-cert-chain.html

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of passing userName and Password? What if I am writing a Java Client, do I need to pass the userName and password in the header of the GET request , in that case?

Comment: @Shubhi224 not if your https server does not require a simple authentication for GET requests. I had to use authentication since it was a REST call which required it.

Comment: As mentioned in this answer "You need to provide the entire certificate chain to curl, since curl no longer ships with any CA certs."

Answer (score 27):

use `--cacert` to specify a `.crt` file. 
`ca-root-nss.crt` for example.

Answer (score 8):

I actually had this kind of problem and I solve it by these steps:

1. Get the bundle of root CA certificates from here: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and save it on local
2. Find the `php.ini` file
3. Set the `curl.cainfo` to be the path of the certificates. So it will something like:

`curl.cainfo = /path/of/the/keys/cacert.pem`

Answer (score 6):

[Here you could find the CA certs with instructions to download and convert Mozilla CA certs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).
Once you get `ca-bundle.crt` or `cacert.pem` you just use:

```
curl.exe --cacert cacert.pem https://www.google.com
```

or

```
curl.exe --cacert ca-bundle.crt https://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 2):

having dignosed the problem 
I was able to use the existing system default CA file, on debian6 this is:

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

as root this can be done like:

```
echo curl.cainfo=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt >> /etc/php5/mods-available/curl.ini
```

then re-start the web-server.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this

`curl_setopt($curl->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Answer (score 1):

You need the certificates chain and not a single certificate.
It is easy to get it using Firefox:

1. Open the url in Firefox.
2. Click on the security icon on the address box left to the url.
3. Click on `connection not secure`, `more information`. Under the `security` tab, select `view certificate`, scroll toward the end. Next to `download`, select the **PEM(chain)** to download the chain of certificates.

Now you have the chain of certificates as a file that you can use in the curl request after the `--cacert` flag: 
`curl --cacert downloaded.pem -X POST  https://the-url-to-access`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just wanted to test a website that had an automatic http->https redirect. I think I had some certs installed already, so this alone works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 running `curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3`

`curl --proto-default https <target>`

Answer (score 0):

**Converting a Java KeyStore (.jks) to a Privacy Enhanced Mail file (.pem)**

Use keytool to convert the JKS into PKCS:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.pkcs -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12
```

Now convert the PKCS into PEM by using openssl:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.pkcs -out certificate.pem
```

Answer (score -4):

With modern versions of curl, you can simply override which ip-address to connect to, using --resolve or --connect-to (curl newer than version 7.49). This works even with SSL/SNI. All details are in the man page.

For example, to override DNS and connect to www.example.com with ssl using a particular ip address: (This will also override ipv6)

```
curl --resolve www.example.com:443:192.168.42.2 https://www.example.com/
```

Another example, to connect to a particular backend server named backend1 on port 8080

```
curl --connect-to www.example.com:80:backend1.example.com:8080 http://www.example.com/
```

Remember to add the host header if the server needs that to answer correctly:

```
-H 'Host:www.example.com'
```

Comment: I am not sure how this answer the question.