# Testing a TCP socket server?

Tags: c++, sockets, openssl

I've written a simple TCP socket server in c++ that uses sys/socket and OpenSSL..

I wish to use this server in production and I haven't been able to find clear methods for testing a socket server at scale.

What are the best methods and/or tool for testing sockets?

Comment: Err, with a test client? Unclear what the difficulty is.

Comment: What do you want to test it for? Do you have requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to write a custom test client, which obviously doesn't have to be in C++, there are some common tools that can be used to connect to your server.  For example, you can use `curl` and `telnet`.  Google for these tools and how to use them if you are not already familiar with them.  The following answers might be helpful:

[https connection using CURL from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079707/https-connection-using-curl-from-command-line)

https://superuser.com/questions/346958/can-the-telnet-or-netcat-clients-communicate-over-ssl